# LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} with forest-GP1

Tags: forest

I'm trying to use forest-GP1 which is a style in Zivanovic's forest-package (for phonological representation) found [on github](https://github.com/sasozivanovic/forest-styles).

I have added the `.sty` file to the same directory as the relevant `.tex` file (I have also tried linking to it by defining the path in `\usepackage{/path/forest-GP1}`, but regardless I end up with the *Missing \begin{document}* error.

Here is the code I've used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest-GP1}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} GP1 [
[O[x[f ] ][x[r ] ] ]
[R[N[x[o ] ] ][x[s ] ] ]
[O[x[t ] ] ]
[R[N[x ] ] ]
]\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

I'm typesetting with PDFLaTeX in TeXWorks (using MiKTeX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, that you are missing **forest-GP1** package and it is not download automatically. Are you sure you included it in the right folder?

You could get it from [github](https://github.com/sasozivanovic/forest-styles/blob/master/forest-GP1.sty) and include it in your working folder as **forest-GP1.sty** and it will work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest-GP1}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} GP1 [
[O[x[f ] ][x[r ] ] ]
[R[N[x[o ] ] ][x[s ] ] ]
[O[x[t ] ] ]
[R[N[x ] ] ]
]\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The error should be different in this case, though... it will complain it cannot find the `.sty` file rather than about a missing `\begin{document}`. At least, that's the error I get...

Comment: You were right, it seems there was something wrong with the forest-GP1.sty I downloaded, I tried again by copy/pasting the forest-GP1 code, and now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could just define the style as show on page 49 of `forest`'s manual:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\newbox\standardnodestrutbox
\setbox\standardnodestrutbox=\hbox to 0pt{\phantom{\forestOve{standard node}{content}}}
\def\standardnodestrut{\copy\standardnodestrutbox}
\forestset{% from page 49 of forest's manual
  GP1/.style 2 args={
    for n={1}{baseline},
    s sep=0pt, l sep=0pt,
    for descendants={
      l sep=0pt, l={#1},
      anchor=base,calign=first,child anchor=north,
      inner xsep=1pt,inner ysep=2pt,outer sep=0pt,s sep=0pt,
    },
    delay={
      if content={}{phantom}{for children={no edge}},
      for tree={
        if content={O}{tier=OR}{},
        if content={R}{tier=OR}{},
        if content={N}{tier=N}{},
        if content={x}{
          tier=x,content={$\times$},outer xsep={#2},
          for tree={calign=center},
          for descendants={content format={\standardnodestrut\forestoption{content}}},
          before drawing tree={outer xsep=0pt,delay={typeset node}},
          s sep=4pt
        }{},
      },
    },
    before drawing tree={where content={}{parent anchor=center,child anchor=center}{}},
  },
  GP1/.default={5ex}{8.0pt},
  associate/.style={%
    tikz+={\draw[densely dotted](!)--(!#1);}},
  spread/.style={
    before drawing tree={tikz+={\draw[dotted](!)--(!#1);}}},
  govern/.style={
    before drawing tree={tikz+={\draw[->](!)--(!#1);}}},
  p-govern/.style={
    before drawing tree={tikz+={\draw[->](.north) to[out=150,in=30] (!#1.north);}}},
  no p-govern/.style={
    before drawing tree={tikz+={\draw[->,loosely dashed](.north) to[out=150,in=30] (!#1.north);}}},
  encircle/.style={before drawing tree={circle,draw,inner sep=0pt}},
  fen/.style={pin={[font=\footnotesize,inner sep=1pt,pin edge=<-]10:\textsc{Fen}}},
  el/.style={content=\textsc{\textbf{##1}}},
  head/.style={content=\textsc{\textbf{\underline{##1}}}}
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{forest} GP1 [
    [O[x[f ] ][x[r ] ] ]
    [R[N[x[o ] ] ][x[s ] ] ]
    [O[x[t ] ] ]
    [R[N[x ] ] ]
    ]\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: GP1]